# Are companies in California obliged to provide invoices?

Tags: united-states

In Europe, for income tax deductible purchases, I need to provide invoices rather than a proof of payment. However, a business in California refuses to send me one, just saying they don't do that. Is that even legal?

Comment: How do you know how much to pay without an invoice?

Comment: littleadv has a very good point. What was it you purchased? How did you pay for it? Was it an online transaction? Was there something on your screen you *could* have printed and used as an invoice?

Comment: I had to pay by credit card, online. So I do have a proof of payment, but a valid invoice must have a tax number, invoice number and company address, to name a few things.
It was for having a credit check for a temporary apartment.

Comment: Which part of Europe are you in? 'Europe' has a variety of tax rules.

Comment: My question is about California, but it's about tax in the Netherlands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We run into this all the time with our EU clients. As far as I can tell, [the only requirements when it comes to invoicing have to do with sales tax](http://www.boe.ca.gov/sutax/faqpurch.htm#3), which is determined at the state level, and only in the case that items are taxable. It seems that the service provided to you [is not taxable](http://www.taxes.ca.gov/Sales_and_Use_Tax/WhatsTaxable.shtml) and so there is no obligation under Californian law to provide you with the invoice you need.

That said, it would be nice to provide this information to you as a courtesy. We don't provide the information typically required by EU tax authorities on our receipts either, but whenever one of our EU clients requests a more formal invoice we gladly send them one.

Comment: Thanks! Only leaves me wondering how Californians have to prove they made tax deductible purchases if they paid these with cash.

Comment: @kslstn for that purpose a receipt showing the nature of the purchase would suffice.